mid-low cost IMU recommendations for AMR in indoor environments
I am looking for some recommendations regarding IMUs for less than $500 which are used in production grade AMRs. Ideally, I would prefer some which already have ros2 driver code available. Another requirement for me would be that the sensor is capable of producing orientation estimates along with the velocity and acceleration. I found some (on the extremely low price end) such as the SEN0253, BNO080, BMI088 etc., but I have been reading extremely mixed reviews regarding their performance.
Does someone have any experience in this area and has gone through this search before? Or maybe you are using one which is giving you good performance (accurate orientation and velocity estimates)? Any recommendations and help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

I've been generally very happy with my BNO055 / BNO080 for my robots. They're cheap, you can buy large volumes of them easily for PCB manufacturing, and there are some dev kits around in a few different form factors for prototyping or getting started for students / home projects. For indoor AMR applications, I've yet to have an issue of remark (that wasn't of my own creation on custom PCB design).
I don't believe I've used the BMI088, but its very possible I have, they're in the same family as the BNO's. Also a good option. I can't speak to the SEN0253.
These are kind of "smart phone" grade IMUs that you'll need to integrate (pending ROS drivers for particular packagings of it), if you want a nice IMU I'd look at MicroStrain 3DM-GX5-IMU -- which I also have and are fabulous sensors with really active ROS support.

I did see the MicroStrain 3DM as well and have short-listed the same. Time to run some tests now :) Thank you for your reply!
